# Continuously write content of a log file into an NSTextview

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, fsevents

I'm having trouble with an NSTextview which should continously update with the contents of a log file. The app is a master-detail UI, the master view contains an array of "backup" objects, while the detail view contains an NSTabView with one of the tabs containing the NSTextview.
Basically I want something like a `tail -f logfile` putting it's output into the NSTextview. Instead of using NSTask etc., I went for binding the NSTextview's "Attributed String" to a property of my "backup" object (so I can set the font):

**backup.m**

```
- (NSAttributedString *)logContent
{
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Monaco" size:12]};
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:theLogfile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
if (str) {
    NSAttributedString *attrstr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:str attributes:attributes];
    return attrstr;
} else
    return nil;
}
```

Then I hook an `FSEventStream` to the logfile which informs a callback everytime the logfile changes. Inside the callback, I manually inform listeners that the property has changed and scroll down the NSTextview:

**backup.m**

```
- (void)_fsEventsCallback:(NSArray *)eventPaths{
if ([eventPaths containsObject:theLogfile.path]){
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"logContent"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"logContent"];
    [_myAppDel.logTextView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([[_myAppDel.logTextView string] length], 0)];
}}
```

The actual remove is done via an `NSNotification`:

**App Delegate.m**

```
- (void)removeBackupObject:(NSNotification *)notification
{
if (notification.object) {
    [self.backupsArrayController removeObject:notification.object];
}
}
```

This works and I like the code better than using an NSTask, but the app occasionally crashes with a strange error when I tell the `NSArrayController` to remove a "backup" object:

```
Crashed Thread:  5  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.low-priority

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSSetM: 0x60000045f1a0> was mutated while being enumerated.'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
abort() called

Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8aec425c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8a7a4e75 objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8aec3b64 __NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler + 164
3   Foundation                          0x00007fff8d0e3f05 -[NSISEngine chooseOutgoingRowHeadForIncomingRowHead:] + 305
4   Foundation                          0x00007fff8d0e1aa8 -[NSISEngine minimizeConstantInObjectiveRowWithHead:] + 114
5   Foundation                          0x00007fff8d0e1623 -[NSISEngine optimize] + 147
6   Foundation                          0x00007fff8d0e851d -[NSISEngine constraintDidChangeSuchThatMarker:shouldBeReplacedByMarkerPlusDelta:] + 296
7   Foundation                          0x00007fff8d0e839e -[NSISEngine tryToChangeConstraintSuchThatMarker:isReplacedByMarkerPlusDelta:undoHandler:] + 420
8   Foundation                          0x00007fff8d0d3798 -[NSLayoutConstraint _tryToChangeContainerGeometryWithUndoHandler:] + 462
9   Foundation                          0x00007fff8d0d31b3 -[NSLayoutConstraint _setSymbolicConstant:constant:] + 402
10  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e2ac4ba -[NSView(NSConstraintBasedLayout) _autoresizingConstraints_frameDidChange] + 247
11  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e2ab25f -[NSView setFrameOrigin:] + 901
12  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e2b51b6 -[NSView setFrame:] + 259
13  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e682c2f -[NSClipView _updateOverhangSubviewsIfNeeded] + 739
14  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e2e80a1 -[NSClipView _scrollTo:animateScroll:flashScrollerKnobs:] + 1984
15  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e2e76ff -[NSClipView _reflectDocumentViewFrameChange] + 128
16  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e2ac0ac -[NSView _postFrameChangeNotification] + 203
17  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e2b5852 -[NSView setFrameSize:] + 1586
18  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e447bac -[NSTextView(NSPrivate) _setFrameSize:forceScroll:] + 764
19  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e3b222f -[NSTextView setConstrainedFrameSize:] + 633
20  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e443f70 -[NSLayoutManager(NSPrivate) _resizeTextViewForTextContainer:] + 1025
21  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e35133e -[NSLayoutManager(NSPrivate) _recalculateUsageForTextContainerAtIndex:] + 2636
22  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e343fb1 _enableTextViewResizing + 211
23  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e34a6ef -[NSLayoutManager textStorage:edited:range:changeInLength:invalidatedRange:] + 557
24  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e34a4aa -[NSTextStorage _notifyEdited:range:changeInLength:invalidatedRange:] + 149
25  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e451a2c -[NSTextStorage processEditing] + 200
26  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e44d832 -[NSTextStorage endEditing] + 110
27  Foundation                          0x00007fff8d10b434 -[NSMutableAttributedString removeAttribute:range:] + 219
28  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e4ca2c1 -[NSTextView setTextColor:] + 156
29  AppKit                              0x00007fff8ea19baf -[_NSTextPlugin showValue:inObject:] + 128
30  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e314797 -[NSValueBinder _adjustObject:mode:observedController:observedKeyPath:context:editableState:adjustState:] + 846
31  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e3143aa -[NSValueBinder _observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:context:] + 282
32  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e314215 -[NSTextValueBinder _observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:context:] + 43
33  Foundation                          0x00007fff8d09af28 NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 387
34  Foundation                          0x00007fff8d0d7ed1 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _notifyObserversForKeyPath:change:] + 1115
35  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e306d88 -[NSController _notifyObserversForKeyPath:change:] + 209
36  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e4385ff -[NSArrayController didChangeValuesForArrangedKeys:objectKeys:indexKeys:] + 125
37  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e62179f -[NSArrayController _removeObjectsAtArrangedObjectIndexes:contentIndexes:objectHandler:] + 724
38  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e621d1f -[NSArrayController _removeObjects:objectHandler:] + 502
```

Before I go into debugging what's going wrong, or implement the `NSTask` / `tail -f` approach, I'd like to know:

Are there are more elegant solutions to this problem?

Comment: It seems that there's a concurrency problem: two threads accessing the same resource at the same time. Is the callback executed on the main thread or on a different one?

Comment: If a different one, update the ui on your main thread. Try using performSelector:OnMainThread.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The actual call to `removeObject:` is done via a notification. I've updated the post.

Answer (score 2):

This is an unsynchronized access issue. The notification is executing on one thread and the fsevent callback on another and both of them are accessing the ArrayController's underlying    array and the textview at the same time.

### Option 1 - Quick and dirty fix

Synchronize access accross threads. This done by acquiring a lock on the particular resource being accessed: the executing thread is gets the lock and all threads that attempt to acess that resource will be blocked until the locking thread releases the lock. More info can be found in the [Threadding programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW1)

Your code thus becomes:

```
- (void)_fsEventsCallback:(NSArray *)eventPaths{
    if ([eventPaths containsObject:theLogfile.path])
        @synchronized(self.logContent) {
            [self willChangeValueForKey:@"logContent"];
            [self didChangeValueForKey:@"logContent"];
        }
        @synchronized(_myAppDel.logTextView.string) {
            [_myAppDel.logTextView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([[_myAppDel.logTextView string] length], 0)];
        }
    }
}

- (void)removeBackupObject:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if (notification.object) {
      @synchronized(self.backupsArrayController) {
          [self.backupsArrayController removeObject:notification.object];
      }
    }
}
```

This will most likely solve your immediate problem, but however, IT IS A CHEAP AND DIRTY FIX and will effectively make your application's threads wait for each other every time.

### Option 2 - The better way

Always update your ui on the main thread and do actual work on secondary threads.

The FSEvents callback is called on a secondary thread, the NSNotification that you are posting is responded to on another secondary thread and all of them operate on objects that are not really thread safe. Generally, NSMutable* objects are thread safe on access but not on mutations. In other words, if you're altering their contents, you'd better pay attention whos is doing what and when. :)

More info on which Cocoa Objects are thread safe and which are not can be found here in the [Thread Safety](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH12-SW1) section in the document I referred above. (That is quite a good piece of reading btw)

The idea is to tell the app to update the interface on the main thread, like so:

```
- (void)_fsEventsCallback:(NSArray *)eventPaths{
if ([eventPaths containsObject:theLogfile.path]){
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"logContent"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"logContent"];
    [[NSApp delegate] performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(scrollToWhereWeNeedTo) withObject:nil];
}}
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (void)scrollToWhereWeNeedTo
{
    [self.logTextView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([[self.logTextView string] length], 0)];
}

- (void)removeBackupObject:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if (notification.object) {
        [[NSApp delegate] performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(removeObjectFromArrayController) withObject:notification.object];

    }
}

- (void)removeObjectFromArrayController:(id)theObject
{
       [self.backupsArrayController removeObject:theObject];
}
```

What you are effectively doing here is you are scheduling the scroll operation and the removing object operations on the main thread's runloop, thus eliminating any potential access conflict, because they will be in a queue, one after the other.

Also, please look at any other potential places in your app where access conflicts could happen.

I really hope this helps and does not confuse you even further. Cocoa can be a pain at first but hey, what doesn't kill you makes you stronger!

Comment: Thanks, you're right the `removeObject:` call needs to happen on the main thread. As soon as I have one more rep point I'll vote your answer up.

Comment: It's not only that. Be sure that you properly synchronize access to the collectioon of elements that the array controller manages.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with the help of [Cătălin Stan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2338722/ctlin-stan)  by executing the `removeObject:` call on the main thread like so:

```
- (void)removeBackupObject:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if (notification.object) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.backupsArrayController removeObject:notification.object];
        });
    }
}
```